# Does anyone have a complete mapping from manifest permissions to user-displayed permissions on Android?

Tags: android

[This](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en) is the list of permissions the user may have to accept. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) is the list of permissions the developer may request. Have anyone bothered to create a mapping between the two? It would be very useful in order to explain why a certain permission is requested from the user's perspective. It's not always obvious.

Comment: My advice is, you should explain any permission you add in the manifest regardless if its shown when the user installs the app. If for example you are implementing a new feature and you realize you need a new permission for it to work, state that in the description "I added internet permission to fetch X data from a server" or "I need Bluetooth permission to share data via bluetooth with your friends"